# How to orderby and combine types of the same index in laravel search when using scount with elasticsearch?

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, laravel-5, laravel-scout

I have a Laravel application. I installed elasticsearch server and implemented it to laravel using `scout` and `tamayo/laravel-scout-elastic`.

All is working almost perfectly. I have two questions that I can't find the answer to.

1. How to order the output of the results by most words matching. Or `_score of the elastic results`
2. How to combine two types of the same index? I have index by the name of `news` how to combine `world news` and `sports news`?

I am using this method to make the search:

`$searched = Model::search($q)->get();`

In the model I've included the `Scout`

`use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;` and `use Searchable;`

Answer (score 0):

1. You can pass callback to search method and customize request https://laravel.com/docs/master/scout#customizing-engine-searches
2. There is no way to do it with `tamayo/laravel-scout-elastic` but you can do it with https://github.com/matchish/laravel-scout-elasticsearch if you ready to move types in separated indices. In Elasticsearch 7 mapping types have been removed so I recommend do it anyway.